# URL hash page jump... fixed header overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header, nav

So here's the deal,

I have a fixed header/navbar, and when I jump to something via a #urlhash it overlaps it.

Now I could add a div that goes before the content and jump to that, but that would end up messing the whole style up.

So I'm wondering, is there a JavaScript/jQuery trick to add about 200px of padding after a jump?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an absolute positioned empty (&nbsp;) div with top:-200px and jump to that. Just make sure the parent element is not statically positioned (relative should do the trick)

Comment: Problem with that is I'd need to re-write a huge amount of code on the site for that. I'm looking for a simple fix.

Comment: If you already have named anchors within divs, you may only need to modify some CSS to work with your existing markup. Maybe if I saw the page I could offer some more specific advice

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(window).onload(function() {
    if (document.location.hash)
        $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 200);
});
```

Comment: Thought it'd work, but nope...

`$(window).ready(function() {
    if (location.location.hash)
        window.scrollTop(window.scrollTop + 200);
});`

doesn't work either

Comment: try it now, i was missing the `()` by the `scrollTop`

Comment: Unfortunately that failed too :-/